# Delivering content-type when known, but not by extension

Tags: html, http-headers, mime-types, content-type

I run a phpBB board, where attachments are uploaded stored without extension - however, the mime-type is stored in the database.  When delivering the attachment for display, I want to be able to specify Content-Type header based on the type, which cannot be derived from the stored filename.  [Here is a simple example](http://www.59plymouth.net/content-type/test.html) - If you click on the left icon where the extension is specified, the video plays.  If you click on the right icon sans extension, but where "type" is specified, it downloads the video because the content-type is not known.  How do I tell the server, to deliver the appropriate content-type of "video/mp4" in this particular example?

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="./media/2.mp4"><img src="./media/2_thumb.jpg"/></a>
<a href="./media/2" type="video/mp4"><img src="./media/2_thumb.jpg"/></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh, and just to note - I can have mixed media, so it won't do to fix the Content-Type for all references on that page. I want to be able to click a hyperlink, and trigger the transmission of the appropriate Content-Type for the object referenced in that link.

Dan

Comment: BTW, I've yet to have someone reply to any question I've posted on StackOverflow.  I'm a bit discouraged.  -Dan